# Attempts to concatenate different videos not working out as expected

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to concatenate a variety of videos into a single video. As can be seen below in the output of `ffprobe` for 4 example videos, they are all different in a few ways.

Ideally, I'd like to normalise each to some specific size - say 1280x720 - and then concatenate them.

I've been trying variations of something like this:

```bash
ffmpeg -hide_banner -loglevel error -i ./tmp/1.mp4 -i ./tmp/2.mp4 -i ./tmp/3.mp4 -i ./tmp/4.mp4 
-filter_complex "[0:v]scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=1,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1[var0];
[1:v]scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=1,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1[var1];
[2:v]scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=1,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1[var2];
[3:v]scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=1,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1[var3];[var0][0:a:0][var1][1:a:0][var2][2:a:0][var3][3:a:0]concat=n=4:v=1:a=1[v][a]" 
-map [v] -map [a] ./tmp/output.mp4
```

This doesn't error, but create a file that seemly never stops growing.

I'm pretty new to ffmpeg, but I've been researching this for a while now with little luck. Any help would be appreciated!

Below are the details for each file.

**1.mp4**

```
Input #0, matroska,webm, from '1.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Chrome
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
  Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, mono, fltp (default)
  Stream #0:1(eng): Video: vp9 (Profile 0), yuv420p(tv), 1620x910, SAR 1:1 DAR 162:91, 24.83 fps, 24.83 tbr, 1k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      alpha_mode      : 1
```

**2.mp4**

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '2.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
    encoder         : Lavf59.27.100
  Duration: 00:00:09.05, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 793 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Audio: mp3 (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, mono, fltp, 64 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #0:1[0x2](und): Video: mjpeg (Progressive) (mp4v / 0x7634706D), yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 4963x3062 [SAR 72:72 DAR 4963:3062], 164635 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
```

**3.mp4**

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '3.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
    encoder         : Lavf59.27.100
  Duration: 00:00:10.20, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 957 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](eng): Audio: opus (Opus / 0x7375704F), 48000 Hz, mono, fltp, 50 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #0:1[0x2](und): Video: png (mp4v / 0x7634706D), rgb24(pc), 2667x1500 [SAR 7874:7874 DAR 889:500], 230945 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
```

**4.mp4**

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '4.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
  Duration: 00:02:12.08, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 311 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 566x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 283:360], 174 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc.
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #0:1[0x2](und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 127 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc.
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
```

Comment: maybe, 4th audio needs to resample `[3:a]aresample=async=1...' or `aresample=48000`

Comment: Thanks! So perhaps the fact that the other 3 are 48000hz and the 4th is only 44100hz might be the problem?

Comment: No. My mistake. At first, different fps. Add `...setsar=1,fps=30[...` or 25

Comment: ok, thanks! I appreciate the help